# Is there a way to configure system-wide word delimiters for text in GNOME/GTK+?

Tags: linux, gnome, gtk

I'm looking for a way to define or view and modify which characters are considered word boundaries by GNOME, similar to the ["select-by-word" characters](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/3.10/txt-select-text.html) used in GNOME Terminal ([related question](https://askubuntu.com/q/8413/184030)) or cutchars in rxvt.

For example, when I am using gedit I can type `abc123xyz` and double-click, but only three characters will be selected, since the numbers are treated as a boundary by default. I see the same behavior in Tomboy, and at least a few other other GNOME/GTK+ applications I've tested. It's also present--and particularly annoying--inside the location bar (but not inside pages) of Google Chrome. Firefox seems OK, I believe since its UI is written in XUL, which is doing its own thing.

Please note that I am looking for a general solution, if one exists--I already know that there are [plugins for gedit](https://code.google.com/p/gedit-click-config/) in particular, and maybe other per-application tweaks, but I want to know if this can be done in a way that affects most or all programs that inherit this behavior from the window manager (I presume?).

Comment: Please also let me know if you can't reproduce this behavior. If that's the case, I suspect it may have something to do with locales.. I'm on Debian wheezy, using GNOME 3, en_US.UTF-8 locale (sometimes fr_FR.UTF-8).

Comment: More research hints that it's maybe not locale-related, but rather a well-established mystery related to the way (all?) Gtk+ applications seem to behave by default: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-list/2011-June/msg00060.html and https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-i18n-list/2011-June/msg00003.html

Comment: Also: http://forums.opensuse.org/english/other-forums/looking-something-other-than-support/461854-anyone-know-how-change-pangos-word-separators.html

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, this was fixed in version 1.34.1. Check [the git log](http://git.gnome.org/browse/pango/log) and the commits between 1.34.0 and 1.34.1 tags. Ubuntu 13.04 has version 1.32.5 of libpango1.0-0 same as sid. So, no joy for now for Debian-based distributions. If you need the library, you may compile it from sources.

This is an issue with the `PangoLogAttr()` function that seems that nobody has reported a bug complaining about it. The issue goes back to 2003 till the current time. Appart of the mails that you supply there are:

- https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-i18n-list/2011-August/msg00000.html
- http://forums.opensuse.org/english/other-forums/looking-something-other-than-support/461854-anyone-know-how-change-pangos-word-separators.html
- The pango blueprint proposal http://www.levien.com/gnome/pango-0.1.html
- The function that defines the words boundary which are following the "Word boundary as defined by UAX#29" https://developer.gnome.org/pango/unstable/pango-Text-Processing.html#PangoLogAttr
- The unicode guidelines word boundaries pango is following http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Word_Boundaries

If my interpretation of the guidelines is correct, then it's expected that a word containing numbers, the word is limited by the numbers the same that by spaces and symbols except the `'`.

To report bugs against pango, just visit this link https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=pango

Comment: Good research, thanks! Strange, though, that even the example given in the guidelines doesn't follow the default of having `.` as a boundary.. In any case, it may be more of a feature request than a bug. Can you include a link to where one might file a bug?

Comment: Thanks again! After some quick searching, it does look like people want this and have indeed filed bugs/feature requests: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=111503 and https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=530427 and https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=97545 at least. Maybe I'll just follow/comment on one of those for now.

Comment: Actually, according to that last one, a fix for my specific "abcc123" example has been committed: https://bug97545.bugzilla-attachments.gnome.org/attachment.cgi?id=242980 . No idea though when that version makes it to my Linux distro.

Comment: It is merged, but it's much more recent than the link in your comment. See here: https://git.gnome.org/browse/pango/commit/pango/break.c?id=1aeb5c840e25a7d8538f701659d77dcd7b3a8444 . Now sure if that version is included in any stable version of a Linux distro at the moment.

Comment: I realized that, even though you do thoroughly answer to the specific case of the word/number boundary annoyance I mentioned (indeed, the main problem I personally wanted fixed), the core of the question hasn't completely been answered. Can you edit your answer to additionally include references to the three issues I mentioned in the second comment and briefly assess the status of those? I'm not sure what you say about `PangoLogAttr()` is correct, and there have also indeed been issues filed related to the feature. Your research definitely deserved the bounty though, thanks yet again!

Answer (score 0):

For Debian 7 (Wheezy):

You can download the source files from Debian and make the changes yourself, then recompile and install the created .deb packages:

Open a root terminal:

```
apt-get install dpkg-dev;
apt-get build-dep libpango1.0-0;
exit;
```

Open a regular terminal:

```
cd; mkdir patch-libpango; cd patch-libpango;
apt-get source libpango1.0-0;
```

Now go to your home folder and open the file `patch-libpango/pango1.0-1.30.0/pango/break.c`, then find this block of code:

```c
/* ---- Word breaks ---- */

/* default to not a word start/end */
attrs[i].is_word_start = FALSE;
attrs[i].is_word_end = FALSE;

if (current_word_type != WordNone)
{
    /* Check for a word end */
    switch ((int) type)
    {
    case G_UNICODE_SPACING_MARK:
    case G_UNICODE_ENCLOSING_MARK:
    case G_UNICODE_NON_SPACING_MARK:
    case G_UNICODE_FORMAT:
        /* nothing, we just eat these up as part of the word */
        break;

    case G_UNICODE_LOWERCASE_LETTER:
    case G_UNICODE_MODIFIER_LETTER:
    case G_UNICODE_OTHER_LETTER:
    case G_UNICODE_TITLECASE_LETTER:
    case G_UNICODE_UPPERCASE_LETTER:
        if (current_word_type == WordLetters)
        {
            /* Japanese special cases for ending the word */
            if (JAPANESE (last_word_letter) ||
                    JAPANESE (wc))
            {
                if ((HIRAGANA (last_word_letter) &&
                            !HIRAGANA (wc)) ||
                        (KATAKANA (last_word_letter) &&
                            !(KATAKANA (wc) || HIRAGANA (wc))) ||
                        (KANJI (last_word_letter) &&
                            !(HIRAGANA (wc) || KANJI (wc))) ||
                        (JAPANESE (last_word_letter) &&
                            !JAPANESE (wc)) ||
                        (!JAPANESE (last_word_letter) &&
                            JAPANESE (wc)))
                attrs[i].is_word_end = TRUE;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            /* end the number word, start the letter word */
            attrs[i].is_word_end = TRUE;
            attrs[i].is_word_start = TRUE;
            current_word_type = WordLetters;
        }

        last_word_letter = wc;
        break;

    case G_UNICODE_DECIMAL_NUMBER:
    case G_UNICODE_LETTER_NUMBER:
    case G_UNICODE_OTHER_NUMBER:
        if (current_word_type != WordNumbers)
        {
            attrs[i].is_word_end = TRUE;
            attrs[i].is_word_start = TRUE;
            current_word_type = WordNumbers;
        }

        last_word_letter = wc;
        break;

    default:
        /* Punctuation, control/format chars, etc. all end a word. */
        attrs[i].is_word_end = TRUE;
        current_word_type = WordNone;
        break;
    }
}
else
{
    /* Check for a word start */
    switch ((int) type)
    {
    case G_UNICODE_LOWERCASE_LETTER:
    case G_UNICODE_MODIFIER_LETTER:
    case G_UNICODE_OTHER_LETTER:
    case G_UNICODE_TITLECASE_LETTER:
    case G_UNICODE_UPPERCASE_LETTER:
        current_word_type = WordLetters;
        last_word_letter = wc;
        attrs[i].is_word_start = TRUE;
        break;

    case G_UNICODE_DECIMAL_NUMBER:
    case G_UNICODE_LETTER_NUMBER:
    case G_UNICODE_OTHER_NUMBER:
        current_word_type = WordNumbers;
        last_word_letter = wc;
        attrs[i].is_word_start = TRUE;
        break;

    default:
        /* No word here */
        break;
    }
}
```

and replace it with this:

```c
/* ---- Word breaks ---- */

/* default to not a word start/end */
attrs[i].is_word_start = FALSE;
attrs[i].is_word_end = FALSE;

if (current_word_type != WordNone)
{
    /* Check for a word end */
    switch ((int) type)
    {
    case G_UNICODE_SPACING_MARK:
    case G_UNICODE_ENCLOSING_MARK:
    case G_UNICODE_NON_SPACING_MARK:
    case G_UNICODE_FORMAT:
        /* nothing, we just eat these up as part of the word */
        break;

    case G_UNICODE_LOWERCASE_LETTER:
    case G_UNICODE_MODIFIER_LETTER:
    case G_UNICODE_OTHER_LETTER:
    case G_UNICODE_TITLECASE_LETTER:
    case G_UNICODE_UPPERCASE_LETTER:
        if (current_word_type == WordLetters)
        {
            /* Japanese special cases for ending the word */
            if (JAPANESE (last_word_letter) ||
                    JAPANESE (wc))
            {
                if ((HIRAGANA (last_word_letter) &&
                            !HIRAGANA (wc)) ||
                        (KATAKANA (last_word_letter) &&
                            !(KATAKANA (wc) || HIRAGANA (wc))) ||
                        (KANJI (last_word_letter) &&
                            !(HIRAGANA (wc) || KANJI (wc))) ||
                        (JAPANESE (last_word_letter) &&
                            !JAPANESE (wc)) ||
                        (!JAPANESE (last_word_letter) &&
                            JAPANESE (wc)))
                attrs[i].is_word_end = TRUE;
            }
        }

        last_word_letter = wc;
        break;

    case G_UNICODE_DECIMAL_NUMBER:
    case G_UNICODE_LETTER_NUMBER:
    case G_UNICODE_OTHER_NUMBER:

        last_word_letter = wc;
        break;

    default:
        if (wc == 0x005F) break; //underscore
        /* Punctuation, control/format chars, etc. all end a word. */
        attrs[i].is_word_end = TRUE;
        current_word_type = WordNone;
        break;
    }
}
else
{
    /* Check for a word start */
    switch ((int) type)
    {
    case G_UNICODE_LOWERCASE_LETTER:
    case G_UNICODE_MODIFIER_LETTER:
    case G_UNICODE_OTHER_LETTER:
    case G_UNICODE_TITLECASE_LETTER:
    case G_UNICODE_UPPERCASE_LETTER:
        current_word_type = WordLetters;
        last_word_letter = wc;
        attrs[i].is_word_start = TRUE;
        break;

    case G_UNICODE_DECIMAL_NUMBER:
    case G_UNICODE_LETTER_NUMBER:
    case G_UNICODE_OTHER_NUMBER:
        current_word_type = WordNumbers;
        last_word_letter = wc;
        attrs[i].is_word_start = TRUE;
        break;

    default:
        /* No word here */
        break;
    }
}
```

Go back to your regular terminal:

```c
cd ~/patch-libpango/pango*;
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -b;
```

Now go to your home folder and open the folder `patch-libpango`, you should find some `.deb` files there.
Install them all except for the debug and doc packages (the ones that have -dbg and -doc in their filename)

You can now delete the `patch-libpango` directory, go back to your regular terminal:

```c
cd; rm -rf patch-libpango;
```

Done, you don't need to restart your system.

Note: this will also treat the underscore as part of a word (find 0x005F in the edited code).

References:

- https://git.gnome.org/browse/pango/commit/pango?id=1aeb5c840e25a7d8538f701659d77dcd7b3a8444
- https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-sourcehandling.en.html